# Will the existing IP's lose access if we add a new IP in the Azure Database Firewall?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL Database with around 100 users IP's added. Then I want to add a new IP.
Now I am in a doubt if the gateway gets restarted or not if I update the firewall rules(Add
a New IP).
If the gateway restarts all my 100 users and my deployed api's in the app services will lose Connectivity to my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the existing IPs in the list will remain open for the connection. [Adding new IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#create-and-manage-ip-firewall-rules) to list won't affect the existing IP list.

Comment: So my gateway won't get restarted and all my azure services should remain intact right?

Comment: It can take from couple of secs to mins at max to reflect but I don't think there would be any downtime or affecting already listed IPs

Comment: I tried to search over internet and could not find anything about restart or so. But one of our team members observed and suspected there could be some down time when one of the app service call services failed after an IP addition.

Comment: Can you eloborate on your setup, app service and gateway sql connection. What I see from your question title and content is, "You already have few explicit IPs whitelisted under az sql db firewall settings, and now you want to add just one more, and checking if this new IP record adding to list will cause any disruption in sql connections" correct me if wrong.

Comment: you can take a look at the architecture [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture#connectivity-architecture)

Comment: Yes you are right. My question title is states the user ip's. In the elaborated question you can find the query related to api's and app services. Thank you for the documentation. As per my understanding, all the internal services should not be effected due to these firewall rules. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: correct, I could find the right document to complement the direct question though.